# Net of a Triangular Prism

Tags: geometry

I have participated in the AMC8 Mathematics Competition from the United States of America in the past year, and I got a single question wrong. Now, I have discovered a website that has the questions, so I checked it out, and still could not figure out how to do that question. Could anyone please help me? Here is the link to the website: https://ivyleaguecenter.files.wordpress.com/2022/01/2022-amc-8-problems-and-answers.pdf

The question states:

The figure below shows a polygon $$, consisting of rectangles and right triangles. When cut out and folded on the dotted lines, the polygon forms a triangular prism. Suppose that $ =  = 8$ and $ = 14$. What is the volume of the prism?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$EF$ meets $GF$, and $AB$ meets $CB$, so we can mark a number of edges as length $8$ and see that $GJ$ is length $6$.

Then the area of triangle $BGJ$ is $8 \times 6 / 2 = 24$.

The volume of the pyramid is that area times length of $BC$.

Volume = $24 \times 8 = 192$

[image]

Comment: Hello, may I ask how did you annotate the image?

Comment: With MS Paint. I could have used any basic image/graphics editor.

Comment: Thank you very much!